# Converting Kobo EPUB format to Kindle format

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, conversion

How can I transfer/convert Kobo ebooks on my PC for my Kindle Paperwhite/Kindle PC app?  I'm not very computer literate so, if possible, please use the 'kiss principle' as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the program [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/). This is an eBook management program (Windows, Mac and Linux) which can sync ebooks from your PC to Kindle. Also, it will convert most files so they are compatible with your Kindle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [KindleGen](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwie_-3XgvvSAhWBvI8KHVtrB-4QFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Ffeature.html%3FdocId%3D1000765211&usg=AFQjCNETDyjMlndW9iho3Tm0emQGtVaovQ) from Kindle for the OS you are using.  It'll create a mobi file for you from the epub source.  It's available for Windows/Linux/Mac.  It's also very small compared to the size of Calibre, though you get a hell lot of features with [Calibre](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiFud7Hg_vSAhWHso8KHU2HBVwQFggmMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcalibre-ebook.com%2Fdownload&usg=AFQjCNFOjiu3uPxUr_Ma7CNlrFI3UYqJxQ)